# Bash: Check if percentage is greater than 90?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to send myself a notification when my memory usage goes higher than 90 to avoid freezing / lagging or unexpected crashes.

Issue: `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5359 < 80 ")`

```
#!/bin/bash

INUSE=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')

if (( $INUSE > 90 )); then
    notify-send "Performance Warning" "Your memory usage $INUSE is getting high, if this continues your system may become unstable."
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use a shell like `bash` without floating point support, you can always get `awk` to do the comparison:

```
#! /bin/sh -
memory_usage() {
  free |
    awk -v threshold="${1-90}" '
     $1 == "Mem:" {
       percent = $3 * 100 / $2
       printf "%.3g\n", percent
       exit !(percent >= threshold)
     }'
}
if inuse=$(memory_usage 90); then
   notify-send "Performance Warning" "Your memory usage $inuse is getting high, if this continues your system may become unstable."
fi
```

(replaced bash with sh as there's nothing bash-specific in there).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the arithmetic operator that you are trying to use takes integer, and you are giving it a non integer.

```
#!/bin/bash

INUSE=$(free | grep Mem | awk -v OFMT="%f" '{print $3/$2*100.0}')

if (( "${INUSE%.*}" > 90 )); then
    notify-send "Performance Warning" "Your memory usage $INUSE is getting high, if this continues your system may become unstable."
fi
```

If you take off the trailing `.5359` using `"${INUSE%.*}"` it should work, however this also means that you should use `>=` instead of `>`. Otherwise when `INUSE` is greater than `90` and less than `91` it wouldn't notify.

Comment: Probably unlikely to be a problem in practice but note that `echo Mem: 100000000 1 | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'` outputs `1e-06` instead of `0.000001`. You may want to tweak OFMT to make sure the scientific notation is never used.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for this information, I didn't knew OFMT.